# How to count rows using group by

Tags: sql

I have a table like this.

```html
---------
| block |
---------
| A1    |
| A1    |
| A2    |
| A3    |
---------
```

I want to count found rows using group by, so it would return value like this.

```html
--------------
| total_block|
--------------
| 3          |
--------------
```

What is the correct query to show results like that? I have already tried using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS but it return values = A1, A2, A3. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just want the number of different blocks:

```
select count(distinct block) as total_block from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the very nice approach , but if it has to be done via `group by` then, you can try this.

```
select count(cnt) from (select count(1) as cnt  from table_inner group by block) table_outer;
```